# Interval mailing aiogram 3.0.0b7

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

```
async def periodic(sleep_for):
    while True:
        await sleep(sleep_for)
        if db.mailing_state() == 'on':
            logger.info('Сделали рассылку')
            post = db.get_post(randint(0, len(db.get_keys_posts())))
            for user_id in db.get_all_users():
                try:
                    if post[2]:
                        await bot.send_photo(user_id, post[2], caption=post[1])
                    else:
                        await bot.send_message(user_id, post[1])
                except Exception as _ex:
                    logger.info(f'Не удалось отправить сообщение пользователю - {user_id} Ошибка: {_ex}')


async def start_periodic():
    await create_task(periodic(db.get_time()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info('Bot start!')
    dp.run_polling(bot)
```

I need to make an interval mailing list. I already wrote a function that sends out messages to all db users, but I can't figure out how I can get it to work. Who can help?